# archive all messages account on exchange 2003 receiving multiple copies

Tags: exchange, outlook, archive

I am using microsoft exchange 2003 on windows 2003 small business server.

For the past month or so, the archiver account has been receiving multiple copies (about 15 or so) of each and every email. edit: All copies share the same Message ID.

The machine that hosts exchange is updated religiously and an antivirus scan is run on a daily basis.

So would anyone please have any ideas about how to deal with this
and furthermore, how i would be able to delete the multiple copies of emails from outlook 2003 inbox.

I will edit the entry, answering any questions or updating on my efforts

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the messages are exact duplicates, and not a separate message because some user had their mail account set to forward messages to somewhere else?

Comment: sender, recipient, subject and time are consistent among all duplicate copies. is there something i should check in the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual message ID, this will tell you if they're duplicate copies of the same message or not. If there's a unique message ID for each message, then they're unique messages and not copies of the same message.

Comment: i'm afraid the message ID is identical, thanks
edited the question accordingly

Comment: Are you exluding the Exchange directories and processes from your AV software?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823166

Comment: there are some viruses in the exchange directory, the items are quarantined, I'd have to dismount the mail server to clean them up and I haven't had the chance yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused this, but it is now solved:

I created a new user to receive all email that goes through the Exchange server. As soon as the previous user was deselected, he started to receive single copies of the emails that hadn't yet been downloaded.

I tried using a vba script to delete the multiple copies of received emails, that failed. Finally got around to doing it using one of the various shareware "duplicate delete" programs out there.

Thanks for all the replies.